# Request stuck in one node behind Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache-http-server, load-balancer

I'm running an Apache HTTP Server as a load balancer, with 3 application nodes sitting behind it. Here is a sample configuration,

```
   <Proxy "balancer://apicluster">
         BalancerMember http://node1.com/api
         BalancerMember http://node2.com/api
         BalancerMember http://node3.com/api
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass /api balancer://apicluster
   ProxyPassReverse /api balancer://apicluster
```

If one node goes down and request cannot reach it, Apache can route the request to a working node so no service disruption.

Today a tricky issue happened that one node is in malfunctioning status, but instead of being completely unreachable, any request routed to the node will simply stuck there until timeout. The problem is due to some infrastructure issue and the node host itself it not accessible. In this case, requests are still being routed by Apache to that problematic node and eventually fail for user. Anything I can do in Apache to avoid this?

Comment: +1 I'm also facing this. Anybody have any ideas?